# Discrepancy between didBegin(_:)/didEnd(_:) and allContactedBodies

Tags: sprite-kit

I noticed that SpriteKit does not reliably call `didBegin` for all contacts that occur. So far it seems that `allContactedBodies` is more accurate, and I'm planning on refactoring my code to rely on that.

Checking each contact of each entity on every update seems like the worst case scenario, but I expect to have a very limited set of entities for whom this is critical active at the same time (less than 20) so it might work. However my question is this:

Is there any reliable pattern to this that would allow me to optimise the process? Things like `didBegin` being called at least once per frame for each body whose contacts were changed (which would allow me to only go through the contacts of the entity representing that body).

Comment: I've not yet experienced any error that could be attributed to didBegin: (didBeginContact) not being called. Is this problem reproducible? Can you post some examples?

Comment: It's well reproducible in my application, but might be hard to isolate. It's very easy to track the events and then compare to the `allContactedBodies` list in the frame update. I suspect it manifests when either multiple bodies create collisions with each other around the same time or a collision between two bodies comes and goes very rapidly, e.g. when bouncing.

Comment: When multiple (e.g. 3 - A, b & C) bodies collide with each other in the same frame, didBegin will be called 3 times - once for A & B, once for B & C and then again for A & C. For fast-moving bodies, usePreciseCollisionDetection may be required. Does either of these help?

Comment: Whilst you might be right, it seems odd that the physics engine is able to build the allContactedBodies array, yet unable to call didBegin for each contact.

Comment: Here's some other discussion on possibly related issues
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485232/sprite-kits-didbegincontact-function-is-not-very-accurate-what-should-i-do/23486098
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23756011/how-do-i-correctly-use-allcontactedbodies/23798057#33798172
The details are scarce, but it seems there's something more to this. I was mostly looking for advice from someone who has experience solving these kinds of issues.

Comment: Interesting. It certainly isn't a common problem and the 2nd link is wrong, I think, as multiple collisions within the same update() loop do generate a call to didBegin. Does using usePreciseCollisinDetection help at all?

Comment: My bodies are not moving fast at all, so I haven't tried precise collisions. Are you saying that the principle in the second link (the fact that some collisions may be lost) is wrong or just that the code doesn't make sense? I'm having a closer look at my asserts to see if there are some edge cases I might have missed.

Comment: I think the statement "when collisions happen very rapidly, contacts with multiple nodes are reported simultaneusly. In this case, only one of the collisions will be detected in didBeginContact," is wrong as a generalisation, but I won't rule out that it can happen in exceptional cases. If you put a simple 'print("Contact detected") at the top of didBegin(), does that seem to prove or disprove that some contacts are being missed?

Comment: I would have to see code to get a better understanding of the problem,  I have written performance tests on hundreds of nodes contacting each other to get a feel of limitations for the device, and I have yet to encounter issues with didBeginContact misfiring.