# Possible to join two SKPhysicsBodys without using didBegin()?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am creating an app in which a ball is launched off of and on to rotating circular platforms when the screen is tapped. It looks similar to [this](http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple30/v4/4d/a5/f1/4da5f18e-a10d-cad9-27dd-ea4a76c71cf1/screen696x696.jpeg).

I'm having a problem getting the ball to attach to these platforms.

At first I was using `didBegin()` to detect a collision between the ball and the platform. It worked but I found it to be very inaccurate.

The ball would get attached to the platform maybe 10 or so pixels from the edge of the platform and this inaccuracy increases the faster the ball is moving. So that and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485232/sprite-kits-didbegincontact-function-is-not-very-accurate-what-should-i-do) led me to believe that the event-driven `didBegin()` is not that accurate.

So then I decided  test for collision in the `update()` function. I did this by iterating through the platform's `allContactedBodies()` checking to see if the ball is contacting the platform. This is very accurate and it works perfectly.

The problem I am having is I don't know how to attach the ball to the platform. Because I am no longer using `didBegin()`, I no longer have access to the `SKPhysicsContact.contactPoint` that allowed me to join the two SKPhysicsBodies.

Is there a way to join two `SKPhysicsBodies` without using `didBegin()`? If not, what are my options?

================ SOLUTION ================

I was able to join the two bodies in `update()` by setting the anchor point to be the position of the ball. It was then that I realized that `update()` is not as accurate as I thought, as the ball would attach to the platform a few pixels too far in. This is interesting because when I was using `didBegin()` the ball would be attached to the platform too far OUT. Still unsure of the cause of this, although I suspect it may just be my computer not being able to run the simulator fast enough

Anyways I basically accepted that there is no way to accurately detect collision so my workaround was to use `didBegin()` to detect collision and then reset the ball's position to the correct point on the platform and anchor it and so far this has worked to perfection.

If anyone has a better way to do this please let me know.

Comment: Try this - when you detect that that two bodies are touching, set the ball's velocity to 0. Then wait for `didBegin:` to be triggered for the platform and the ball, which hopefully will have the ball just touching, as the velocity-related inaccuracies may be removed (because the ball's velocity is 0). Then use the `.contactPoint` as before.

Comment: Alternatively, use the 'intersection' function (https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgrect/1455346-intersection) on the CGRects to get the CGRect that defines how they overlap. The origin portion of this CGrect may be accurate enough for your purposes..

Comment: Are you sure it is 10 pixels off?  I have not experienced any problems with collisions, I am going to say either you visually think it is off, but it is not, or you have something coded incorrectly

Comment: Is it possible for the inaccuracy you see to be caused either by your code not reacting fast enough or by the texture of the sprite and it's physics body not matching 100%?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I think I have found a solution. For the record the inaccuracy was not caused by the texture not matching 100%. I verified this by enabling `showPhysics`

Comment: @clenn14 - do you get the same behaviour if you run this on an actual device and not in the simulator?

Comment: @SteveIves yes, still inaccurate but to a lesser degree